# Same URL pattern calling different view functions in Flask

Tags: python, url, routes, flask

I have URL related problem. I have index page and project page(on which can be displayed one of many projects,depending on what projectkey you pass as an argument).
I want to have "pretty" urls so i can have domainname.com/index  and domainname.com/some_project_key calling different view functions

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
pass

@app.route('/<path:projectkey>')
def project(projectkey):
pass
```

This doesn't work for me because if i try going to the index page it will go through index function but before it returns template it will also run project function ,in which it will run query on non existing project.
Is there some built in solution for this or some workaround is needed? 
Any help i can get is much appreciated.

Comment: You have to return. You have no return statement

Comment: @Cfreak There are , but for the sake of simplicity i omitted them here.

Comment: Do you have backslash in the `/index/`? Do not forgot that `@app.route('/index')` and `@app.route('/index/')` work different with and without backslash.

Comment: @tbicr Nope , it's without the backslash at the end of it. 
On a side note, if i put backslash at end in url to have domainname.com/index/ it will call just project function.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code, I just tried it with flask 0.10.1 and everything is working fine, `/` and `/index` call the index() function and all the others including `/index/` call the project function.

Comment: @Peter /index calls index() but before it returns template it also calls project() function. You can put print statements and try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to call your index page from a web browser, remember that many browsers will also make a GET call to the same domain to retrieve your favicon. In my attempt to duplicate this...

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    print 'index'
    return 'index'

@app.route('/<path:projectkey>')
def project(projectkey):
    print 'project'
    return 'project'

app.run(debug=True)
```

After running, I hit the index and received...

```
index
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Oct/2013 18:08:41] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
project
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Oct/2013 18:08:41] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

In other words, this is working. However, "project" is printed because the browser will make a second GET request to `/favicon.ico`.

Comment: That's it. favicon.ico is going to project(projectkey) and causing trouble. Thanks.